# SimpleScheduledRoutePolicy starts a route even the stopDate is in the past

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I'm trying to implement route that runs until certain date. I use SimpleScheduledRoutePolicy to achieve it.
It works fine except the route is started even if the interval defined by startDate and stopDate is in the past when Camel starts up. The route itself is set to autoStartup=false.
Am i missing something?
Thank you,
Radovan

```
  <!-- January,1st at 00:00:00 in milliseconds -->
  <bean id="jan1st-2020-00-00-00" class="java.util.Date">
    <constructor-arg value="1577833200000" type="long"/>
  </bean>
  <!-- stop the route on May, 5th at 00:00:00 -->
  <bean id="stopOnMay5th" class="org.apache.camel.routepolicy.quartz2.SimpleScheduledRoutePolicy">
    <property name="routeStartDate" ref="jan1st-2020-00-00-00"/>
    <property name="routeStopDate" ref="jan1st-2020-00-00-00"/>
  </bean>
...
    <route id="AMQEmptyQueues" autoStartup="false" routePolicyRef="stopOnMay5th">
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the Route starts because you provide a past `routeStartDate` in the `SimpleScheduledRoutePolicy`.

To stop a route, you should not pass a `routeStartDate` at all. See the [examples in the Camel docs](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/simplescheduledroutepolicy.html#_how_it_works) for the arguments of the different operations.